# event keyboard does not work in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I do not know why the event does not work with my script.
It seems logical but I do not know why it does not go to the specified function.
here is my script

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

start = Label(root, text="press 's' to start the game.")
start.pack()
quitGame = Label(root, text="press 'q' to quit the game.")
quitGame.pack()

def start(event):
    if event.char == 's':
        print("Start")

def exit(event):
    if event.char == 'q':
        root.quit


frame = Frame(root, width=800, height=600)
root.bind('<Key>', start)
root.bind('<Key>', exit)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `bind`, you also *un*bind all other function from that event. There is a way to bind multiple functions but in your case it would be better to combine your functions into one.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

start = tk.Label(root, text="press 's' to start the game.")
start.pack()
quitGame = tk.Label(root, text="press 'q' to quit the game.")
quitGame.pack()

def key_pressed(event):
    if event.char == 's':
        print("Start")
    if event.char == 'q':
        root.quit()

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=600)
root.bind('<Key>', key_pressed)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also, try to avoid using wildcard imports; they only lead to confusing code and bugs.

Comment: Or better yet, bind to the specific keypress you're interested in, rather than `'<Key>'`.

Comment: thank you for helping me ... I am new in tkinter , I learned 1 hour before

Comment: how do i do if I press 's' then it will redirect me to another page or frame

Comment: @RóchdíBóuslámá that's an entirely different question. Give it a try yourself and if you can't figure it out make a new post.